# Leader mapping to toggle a vim setting

Tags: vim

There are several Vim settings I love, but are too annoying to always enable. For example:

- `set relativenumber` - annoying when scrolling
- `set list` - distracting when you don't need it

What is a concise leader mapping to toggle a generic Vim setting?

Comment: Sorry, immediately after posting I found the answer. Hope this question helps others.

Comment: I can't find the reference on meta or blog but it is okay to answer you own questions.

Comment: @Xavier, I felt bad answering less than two minutes after asking :/

Comment: @Natan - if you're adding new, relevant information then I don't think there is anything wrong with answering your own question. The voting system takes care of the rest.

Comment: While `set-!` is extremely helpful, I'd love one of these answers to include a procedural/imperative method for non-simple-boolean values (for instance, NeoVim's `:set signcolumn` — it has values like ‘no’ and ‘yes’, so it feels boolean, and is an ideal target for such a toggling-function; but it also supports ‘auto’, so `:set invsigncolumn` or `:set scl!` can't work.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have two ways, as described in the help:

```
                                                           :set-! :set-inv
:se[t] {option}!   or
:se[t] inv{option}      Toggle option: Invert value. {not in Vi}
```

Either

```
:set list!
```

Or

```
:set invlist
```

Will do the same.

Comment: Nice. Immediately changed my key mappings to do:
`:set hlsearch!<CR>`, instead of having to have separate key mappings to enable and disable

Answer (score 14):

Toggle options by appending `!` to `:set <option>`

---

For example, to toggle `relativenumber`:

```
nnoremap <leader>r :set relativenumber!<cr>
```

Comment: For extra friendliness I often add `:set option?` to my mappings after inverting w/ `!`, so `nnoremap <leader>r :set rnu!<cr>:set rnu?<cr>`. This will echo `relativenumber` or `norelativenumber` at the bottom.